# Moving password change from user/%/edit to another existing tab

Tags: 7

I am using the [Authy](https://drupal.org/project/authy) module. I would like to put the Password change form on the Authy page and then I can rename it to something like 'Security Settings'.

I have learn how to change the tab names in template.php, I know how to unset the password fields from the normal page (using [password_tab](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_tab) module as learning guide), but I am stuck on how to actually insert the form into the Authy page.

Any pointers would be welcome.